# Do Roll-Up Summaries ALWAYS Cause Trigger Execution?

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary, order-of-execution

**Per the Save Order of Execution [[link]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm):**

> 18. If the record contains a roll-up summary field or is part of a cross-object workflow, performs calculations and updates the roll-up summary field in the parent record. Parent record goes through save procedure.

Is this true in all cases, even in scenarios where the roll-up summary may be calculating the same value as the existing value (in the case of a COUNT), or if the roll-up summary was previously null and is still null (in the case of a MAX aggregate of a Date Field that doesn't meet filter criteria)?

Say for example you have a roll-up summary on Account that COUNTS child records that meet certain criteria. No child records meet that criteria, so the value is always 0. When a child record is inserted and the count is calculated as 0 again, does that still trigger save procedures for the Account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created this setup in a Scratch Org using a Count Rollup Summary (with filters). In this case, I wanted a Count of Won Opportunities (Won equals true). I created a trigger that would cause a failed assertion when triggered after update on the Account.

I found that I could freely add opportunity records (both create and edit) as long as they were not Closed Won. The trigger was not executed if the parent record was not updated as a result of a child creation or edit.

I also added a validation rule that would trigger on the Account on any edit, and the Rollup Summary field also did not trigger the validation rule as long as there would be no change to the field's value.

So, in summary, the system is efficient enough to not go through the save process on the parent if no changes occurred. You should also be aware, though, that if you add a validation rule to the parent, as long as the rollup field doesn't change value, the validation rule won't affect records that would otherwise be in violation of the validation rule.

Comment: You're right... I don't know what I was doing last night, probably shouldn't test my own theories that late into the evening. I just tried to replicate again this morning and wasn't able to. My mistake